Prove that range $T^\dagger= (\operatorname{null} T)^\perp$
While going through Sheldon Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right, I came across this question

Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional and T $\in$ $L(V, W)$. Show that null $T^\dagger$ = (range $T$)$^\perp$, range $T^\dagger$ = (null $T$)$^\perp$

Although I was able to prove the first part, I have some doubts regarding my 'attempt' on the second part. My attempt to prove that range $T^\dagger$ = (null $T$)$^\perp$ is as follows:

First, let $x$ $\in$ range $T^\dagger$. Recall that $T^\dagger$ is defined as ($T|_{(\text{null T})^\perp})^{-1}$ $P_{\textrm{range T}}$.
Now, $x$ = $T^\dagger$$u$ for some $u$ $\in$ range $T$.
So, $x$ = $T^\dagger u$ = ($T|_{(\text{null T})^\perp})^{-1}$ $P_{\textrm{range T}}$ $u$= ($T|_{(\text{null T})^\perp})^{-1}$ $u$ = $x$ $\implies$ $x$ $\in$ (null $T$)$^\perp$. So, range $T$ $\subset$ (null $T$)$^\perp$.


Now, let $x$ $\in$ (null $T$)$^\perp$. So, $Tx$ $\in$ range $T$. Operating $T^\dagger$ on $Tx$ we obtain, $T^\dagger(Tx)$ = ($T|_{(\text{null T})^\perp})^{-1}$ $P_{\textrm{range T}}$ $(Tx)$ = ($T|_{(\text{null T})^\perp})^{-1}$ ($Tx$) = $x$ $\implies$ $x$ $\in$ range $T^\dagger$. So, (null $T$)$^\perp$ $\subset$ range $T$. Therefore, range $T^\dagger$ = (null $T$)$^\perp$.

My doubt is whether operating $T^\dagger$ can be used to imply that $x$ $\in$ (null $T$)$^\perp$ and $x$ $\in$ range $T^\dagger$. This part feels like it is kind of an intuitive guess and not a rigorous statement.
However, I do not know of any other way to prove the given statement. Is my proof correct? If not, then where am I going wrong? Also, is the '$\implies$' used correctly?

Your proof is not wrong and the '$\implies$' is corrected. However, as you wrote, some parts feel like an intuitive guess. Your $\operatorname{range}T^{\dagger} \subseteq {(\operatorname{null}{T})}^{-1}$ has a mistake as I point out in the following (but this doesn't break the stream of your reasoning), and your ${(\operatorname{null}{T})}^{-1} \subseteq \operatorname{range}T^{\dagger}$ part needs a careful explanation to why the final result is $x$.
Here is how I fix them.
Let $x \in \operatorname{range}{T^{\dagger}}$, then there is $\color{red}{w\in W}$ such that $x = T^{\dagger}w$.
\begin{align*}
  x = T^{\dagger}w & \Longleftrightarrow x = ({(T\vert_{{(\operatorname{null}{T})}^{\bot}})}^{-1}\circ P_{\operatorname{range}{T}})(w) & \text{(the definition of $T^{\dagger}$)} \\
                   & \Longleftrightarrow x = {(T\vert_{{(\operatorname{null}{T})}^{\bot}})}^{-1}(P_{\operatorname{range}T}(w)) \\
                   & \Longrightarrow x \in {(\operatorname{null}{T})}^{\bot}
\end{align*}
the final row is true because ${(T\vert_{{(\operatorname{null}{T})}^{\bot}})}^{-1}$ maps vectors from $\operatorname{range}{T}$ to ${(\operatorname{null}{T})}^{-1}$. Therefore $\operatorname{range}{T^{\dagger}}$ is a subspace of ${(\operatorname{null}{T})}^{\bot}$.
Conversely, let $x \in {(\operatorname{null}{T})}^{\bot}$
\begin{align*}
  T^{\dagger}(Tx) & = ({(T\vert_{{(\operatorname{null}{T})}^{\bot}})}^{-1}\circ P_{\operatorname{range}{T}})(Tx) & \text{(the definition of $T^{\dagger}$)} \\
                  & = {(T\vert_{{(\operatorname{null}{T})}^{\bot}})}^{-1}(Tx) & \text{(because $Tx \in \operatorname{range}{T}$)} \\
                  & = {(T\vert_{{(\operatorname{null}{T})}^{\bot}})}^{-1}(\color{blue}{T\vert_{{(\operatorname{null}{T})}^{\bot}}x}) & \text{(because $x \in {(\operatorname{null}{T})}^{\bot}$)} \\
                  & = x.
\end{align*}
Since $T^{\dagger}(Tx) \in \operatorname{range}{T^{\dagger}}$, it follows that $x\in \operatorname{range}{T^{\dagger}}$. Hence ${(\operatorname{null}{T})}^{\bot}$ is a subspace of $\operatorname{range}{T^{\dagger}}$.
Thus ${(\operatorname{null}{T})}^{\bot} = \operatorname{range}{T^{\dagger}}$.

Comment: I also learned from Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right and worked through the exercises. One thing from the book I appreciate is that he explained almost every line of expression transformation and chain of reasoning. It is an excellent way to make proofs clearer. Learners should do the same to gain a better understanding of the material and what they wrote.
